# In drools, can I have date-effective/date-expires values be set by facts/functions?

Tags: date, drools

I tried using facts to set the values for `date-effective` and `date-expires` in a rule similar to how `salience` can be set dynamically, but keep getting parser errors. Are these attributes fixed at rule parse time or can they be set dynamically?

I couldn't find any further hints, so I just wanted to check if anyone knows if this is possible?

This works for me for dynamic salience:

```
rule "my rule XYZ"
salience $priority
when
    // condition facts
    $rrd : RuleRuntimeData(ruleCode == "xyz", $priority : priority)
...
```

Is something like this possible? And if so what is the syntax?

```
rule "my rule XYZ"
date-expires $dateExpires
date-effective $dateEffective
salience $priority
when
    $rrd : RuleRuntimeData(ruleCode == "xyz", $priority : priority, $dateExpires : endDate, $dateEffective : startDate)
...
```

(I might have to use date facts or an agendafilter instead of the `date-effective` and `date-expires` attributes if it is a value that has to be fixed at rule parse time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that setting these values dynamically would have some use cases. But the idea of defining a time where rules should fire *from the data they are about to evaluate* boggles my mind. Rule evaluation would have to be done, at least partly, to get at a fact T carrying a date/time for date-effective. If the time hasn't arrived yet it should probably fail. But then imagine another rule where another fact X must arrive before evaluation arrives at the fact T carrying a date/time for date-effective. If X arrives past the time given in T, then the evaluation of T will set the date/time to a time in the past and evaluation proceeds. In sum: technical details of LHS evaluation will influence whether a rule succeeds or fails.

Note that dynamic salience is completely different: it merely sets *firing priority* as an afterthought after successful evaluation.

An agenda filter sounds a very reasonable way to define a window of time for rules to be active.

I'm not so sure about "date facts", but who knows - I haven't seen your idea.

Comment: Thanks @laune (as usual :) ). I think I'll go with an agenda filter .. I am currently only looking at fairly simple stateless sessions which evaluate some given facts in a "snapshot" kinda way while the rules are much more static (so I want to avoid rebuilding the kbase as much as possible).